# how can I show the thumbnails from an avi file like Explorer does

Tags: wpf, thumbnails, windows-shell

Need it to work in  WPF
Basically I am showing a list of all vide files in a list control and I want a image frame or thumbnail if you will
was wondering how explorer does it ?

Answer (score 0):

it probably does what you expect: it reads some of the file, uses the appropriate codec to decode some video, and then creates an image from one or more frames.